# Alignment of subplots in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to align a larger figure with two smaller subplots that should be of the same size and reach to the `below south east` and `below south west` anchors of the main figure. The example below does not work because I cannot provide two different alignments for the `two` and `three` axes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=one, width=20cm, height=8cm]
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=two,
    at=(one.below south), anchor=above north east
    ]
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=three,
    at=(one.below south), anchor=above north west,
    yticklabel pos=right,
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can the lower figures can be extended from `one.below south` so that `one.below south west` matches `two.above north west` and `one.below south east` matches `three.above north east`? I think that finding the length of the horizontal axis in the first figure would also help but I don't know how this length can be obtained or defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By setting `scale only axis`, the `width` specifies the width of the axis (not the overall plot with the labels). That way, you can set the widths of the smaller plots to precisely half the width of the main plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=one, width=10cm, height=4cm, scale only axis]
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=two,
    width=5cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
    at=(one.below south), anchor=above north east
    ]
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=three,
    width=5cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
    at=(one.below south), anchor=above north west,
    yticklabel pos=right,
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution!