# Special design of 3 plots with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish design 3 plots (A, B and C) in the form of:

```
------------------------+---------------+
                        |               |
          A             |               |
                        |               |
------------------------+        C      |
                        |               |
          B             |               |
                        |               |
------------------------+---------------+
```

I am using PGFPLOTS package, I check the groupplot section in the user's guide but I didn't figure out how to deal with this disposition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131749/alignment-of-subplots-in-pgfplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution using Jake suggestion. Clearly you have to eliminate some ticks or to move them on the opposite axis to have a good looking plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,height=5cm,width=7cm,name=first plot,xtick=\empty,]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,height=5cm,width=7cm,name=second plot,
anchor=north west,at={(first plot.south west)}]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,height=10cm,width=7cm,name=third plot,
anchor=north west,at={(first plot.north east)}]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A another solution comes to my brain, I think it will be fancy to create an invisible table with 2 columns and put the plots inside them.